# Cannot GET req.query // Cannot GET

Tags: node.js, express

How do i get the result, cause its bad request 404

```
route.get('/all?page=1&perPage=6', postController.findAll);


exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
    const perPage = req.query.perPage || 6;

    Post.findAll(currentPage, perPage, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || 'some error occurred while find posts' });
        res.send(data);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Express guide for [Routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html):

> Query strings are not part of the route path.

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
route.get('/all', postController.findAll);
```